# React async state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a problem with state synchronization. When I click on the outside of the editor (wanna close it) I want to pass the actual text back to parent node (`callback` function).
But when I click outside the `queryText` state seems to be always one step behind. (E.g.: If there is `abc` inside the Editor, I type `d`, `CALLBACK: abc`, I type `e`, `CALLBACK: abcd` and so on...).

How can I achieve that if I click outside of my Editor there will be the actual state of `queryText`?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import AceEditor from "react-ace";

import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/mode-mysql";
import "ace-builds/src-noconflict/theme-eclipse";
import "./SQLEditor.css"


function SQLEditor({queryTab, active, callback}) {
    const [queryText, setQueryText] = useState(queryTab[active].content)

    //Setting a onClickListener somewhere else
    //This function is getting called when I click outside of the Editor
    function handleClickOutside() {
            document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
            console.log("CALLBACK:" + queryText) //Problem here
            callback(active, {content: queryText})
            setInEditor(false)
        }
    }

    //Implementing useEffect for debugging

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(queryText); //Here I'm getting the right one.
    }
    return (
            <AceEditor
                mode="mysql"
                theme="eclipse"
                name="blah2"
                onChange={(newValue) => {
                    setQueryText(newValue) //Seting text to new value
                    console.log(newValue) //Getting the correct updated value
                }}
                fontSize={16}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
export default SQLEditor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below `useEffect`,

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(!inEditor){
        callback(active, {content: queryText});
        console.log(queryText);
    }
}, [inEditor, queryText])
```

And update your `handleClickOutside` to,

```
function handleClickOutside() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    setInEditor(false);
}
```

Comment: You are an angle! Thx

Answer (score 1):

I've haven't seen useEffect return a whole component before and I can't get your code to run in a sandbox. However, I had the same issue the other day getting my state to be synchronous. Here's how I handled it

1. Create `useState` hook that gets **set on click**
2. Add the state to your `useEffect` dependency list
3. **Move on click actions** to your `useEffect` method

It could look something like this

```
const [someVar, setSomeVar] = useState(null);

const handleClick = (e) => {
    setSomeVar(e.target.value); // or whatever
}

useEffect(() => {
    if (someVar != null) { // useEffect will get called on mount, so this logic is to ensure it will only get called if someVar is not equal to it's default value
        // implement handle click logic here
    }
}, [someVar]) // useEffect will get called each time someVar gets updated because we've added someVar to useEffect's dependencies
```